# Use smarty variable in assigned variable

Tags: php, variables, smarty, assign

I assigned a variable in PHP with fetched data from the database like this:

```
$smarty->assign("text",$result->text);
$smarty->assign("amount",250);
```

in the `$result->text` is `Amount is {$amount}$`

and in my `.tpl` file I use the variable :

```
{$text}
```

but the result shows me :

```
Amount is {$amount}$
```

What is the problem ?

**I UPDATED THIS QUESTION**

Comment: yes still you can follow my answer and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For parsing variable in assigned variable we should use `eval` function:
http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.eval.tpl#id479259

So for this problem when I trying to show message we should use `eval` :

```
{eval $text}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this it will work

```
$smarty->assign("amount",250);
$smarty->assign("text","Amount is {$amount}$");
```

Comment: thanks, is there any way if `text` assignment was before `amount` assignment ? because as I said, in my real code I use a variable from database and I fetched and assign before `amount` assignment.

Comment: @jon php is procedural language. so you can understand.

Comment: @Praveenkalal I know why, but it should be included in the answer instead of a "this works" type of answer. ^^

Comment: @majAfy also in that case you can use the same way.i dont think it wont make any impact that data is static or from database but it should be use after declaration.

Comment: @Praveenkalal sorry, I updated my question with my real code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not declaring/initializing the amount variable value try this

```
$smarty->assign("amount",250);
$smarty->assign("text","Amount is {$amount}$");
```

Comment: thanks, is there any way if `text` assignment was before `amount` assignment ? because as I said, in my real code I use a variable from database and I fetched and assign before `amount` assignment.

Comment: I test your code but not work again, for test I copy/paste your code but not work again and show `Amount is $ `

Comment: Your code has a problem you can not declare $result->text = $amount it will always be empty because you are assinging amount value later. It won't work